# I need to iterate over dictionary with ansible in a generic way

Tags: ansible, iteration

I have a dictionary defines of the type as follows:

```
variables.yml
---
fileName1:
  dict1:
    prop1:
     key: "key"
     value: "value"
    prop2:
     key:"key"
     value: "value"
    prop3:
    ..and so on
  dict2:
    prop1:
     key:"key"
     value: "value"
    prop2:
     key: "key"
     value: "value"
  dict3:

fileName2:
 ...and similar structure follows for fileName 2,3, 4.
```

in my ansible task where i want to iterate I am doing is:

```
- name: invlude variable file
  include_vars: variables.yml

- name: iterate over the dict and sub dict
  debug: msg="{{ item.value }}"
  with_dict: "{{ var[filename] }}"
  when: item.key == "dict1"
```

the output here gives me the value as prop1:... prop2:... prop3:..and so on.
I need to further iterate over like prop* which i tried using

```
- name: iterate over the dict and sub dict
  debug: msg="{{ item.value.item }}"
  with_dict: "{{ var[filename] }}"
  when: item.key == "dict1"
```

But the error being returned as the dict does not have any element as item. 
I need to generic iterate over this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the end result desired is how to refer prop1, prop2 in the above example.
"{{ item.value }}" returns me a further dict which i tried to iterate further using "{{ item.value.item}}" which fails. 
Note: i was trying to refer prop1,prop2..using item.value.item....
@techraf

Comment: I'm not an ansible expert - I don't know it at all, but shouldn't `invlude` be `include`?

Comment: Seems like XY problem...

Answer (score 0):

There has to be a simpler way to do this, but I'm drawing a blank and this way works to be able to iterate through the props:

testvars.yml:

```
---

fileName1:
  dict1:
    prop1:
     key: "key111"
     value: "value111"
    prop2:
     key: "key112"
     value: "value112"
    prop3:
     key: "key113"
     value: "value113"
  dict2:
    prop1:
     key: "key121"
     value: "value121"
    prop2:
     key: "key123"
     value: "value122"

fileName2:
  dict1:
    prop1:
     key: "key211"
     value: "value211"
    prop2:
     key: "key212"
     value: "value212"
    prop3:
     key: "key213"
     value: "value213"
  dict2:
    prop1:
     key: "key221"
     value: "value221"
    prop2:
     key: "key222"
     value: "value222"
```

test.yml:

```
---

- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - include_vars: testvars.yml

  - name: Iterate
    include_tasks: test2.yml
    vars:
      loopitem: "{{ item.value }}"
    with_dict: "{{ fileName1 }}"
    when: item.key == 'dict1'
```

test2.yml

```
---

- debug:
    msg: "Property {{prop.key}} has the keypair {{prop.value.key}} : {{prop.value.value}}"
  with_dict: "{{ loopitem }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: prop
```

Comment: thanks lot for help. As you thought of, i made a simpler way to do this, i broke it down into smaller dictionaries.
I just wanted to know if ansible has a capability to do this without handling any complexity at my end.